# Schdulable class doesnt send emails on product org while same code works in test org

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

Im testing the code in Anonymous Window with this code:

```
NotificationNameOptions abc = new NotificationNameOptions(); 
abc.execute(null);
```

On production org I get this error:

```
Line: 12, Column: 1
System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email address is invalid: null: [toAddresses, null]
```

Here is code for NotificationNameOptions class:

```
global class NotificationNameOptions implements Schedulable {
    global void execute (SchedulableContext ctx) {
        sendNotificationEmail();
    }
    public void sendNotificationEmail() {
        
             String temat='Wygasające oferty pracy:\n';
             String temat1='Wygasające oferty pracy:\n';
             String temat2='Wygasające oferty pracy:\n';
             String temat3='Wygasające oferty pracy:\n';
             String temat4='Wygasające oferty pracy:\n';
     
            List<Job_offer__c> dane;
            dane = [SELECT Recruitment_end_date__c, Name FROM Job_offer__c WHERE Recruitment_end_date__c = NEXT_N_DAYS:7 AND Recruitment_end_date__c>=Today ];
            
            for (Job_offer__c a:dane){
                temat = temat + a.Name +' '+ a.Recruitment_end_date__c + '\n';
            }
                
            
            String email1 = NotificationMails__c.getInstance().mail1__c; 
            String email2 = NotificationMails__c.getInstance().mail2__c; 
            String email3 = NotificationMails__c.getInstance().mail3__c; 
            
            System.debug('****************Adres email : '+ email1);
      
            if (dane.size() >0 ){
                EmailManager em = new EmailManager();
                em.sendMail(email1, 'Wygasające oferty pracy', temat);
                em.sendMail(email2, 'Wygasające oferty pracy', temat);
                em.sendMail(email3, 'Wygasające oferty pracy', temat);
            } else {
                System.debug('Nie poszło');
            }          
    }
}
```

And here for EmailManager:

```
public class EmailManager {
    // Public method
    public void sendMail(String address, String subject, String body) {
        // Create an email message object
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {address};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject(subject);
        mail.setPlainTextBody(body);
        // Pass this email message to the built-in sendEmail method 
        // of the Messaging class
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(
                                 new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        
        inspectResults(results);
    }
    
    // Helper method
    private static Boolean inspectResults(Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results) {
        Boolean sendResult = true;
        
        for (Messaging.SendEmailResult res : results) {
            if (res.isSuccess()) {
                System.debug('Email sent successfully');
            }
            else {
                sendResult = false;
                System.debug('The following errors occurred: ' + res.getErrors());                 
            }
        }
        
        return sendResult;
    }
}
```

Body of NotificationNameOptions in Anonymous Window sends email correctly. There seem to be an issue when the class should work as Schedulable class.

What else can I check for solution?

Comment: Any chance that there are no custom settings or one of the mail*__c fields is empty there? That what it actually says -- ```Email address is invalid: null: ```

Comment: Yes, just checked and one of the emails were null. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @kurunve - looks like you should post as the answer